# Recursive Iterators

Tags: c#, recursion, iterator

I am having some trouble making an iterator that can traverse the following type of data structure.

I have a class called `Expression`, which has one data member, `a List<object>`.

This list can have any number of children, and some of those children might be other Expression objects.

I want to traverse this structure, and print out every non-list object (but I do want to print out the elements of the list of course), but before entering a list, I want to return "begin nest" and after I just exited a list, I want to return "end nest".

I was able to do this if I ignored the class wherever possible, and just had `List<object>` objects with `List<object>` items if I wanted a subExpression, but I would rather do away with this, and instead have an `Expression`s as the sublists (it would make it easier to do operations on the object. I am aware that I could use extension methods on the `List<object>` but it would not be appropriate (who wants an `Evaluate` method on their list that takes no arguments?).

The code that I used to generate the origonal iterator (that works) is:

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator(){
        return theIterator(expr).GetEnumerator();
    }
    private IEnumerable theIterator(object root) {
        if ((root is List<object>)){
            yield return " begin nest ";
            foreach (var item in (List<object>)root){
                foreach (var item2 in theIterator(item)){
                    yield return item2;
                }
            }
            yield return " end nest ";
        }
        else
            yield return root;
    }
```

A type swap of `List<object>` for expression did not work, and lead to a stackOverflow error. How should the iterator be implemented?

**Update:** Here is the swapped code:

```
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
    private IEnumerable theIterator(object root) {
        if ((root is Expression)) {
            yield return " begin nest ";
            foreach (var item in (Expression)root) {
                foreach (var item2 in theIterator(item))
                    yield return item2;
            }
            yield return " end nest ";
        }
        else
            yield return root;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the swapped code (the one that gives the `StackOverflowException`)?

Comment: What’s the name of the `List<object>` property in `Expression`?

Comment: "This list can have any number of children, and some of those children might be other Expression objects."  What are the other elements of the list?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Just other types of objects. They inherit from a base class that I wrote called node (note: Expression does not inherit from that class) but I don't think that is relevant (none of that code gets called in this iterator block, according to my debugger).

Comment: Any chance there is any kind of "Parent" property? That would make it blow up. Also: IList or IEnumerable (both non-generic) is probably a better choice to look for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a `StackOverflowException` is that

```
foreach (var item in (Expression)root)
```

…internally causes:

```
((Expression)root).GetEnumerator()
```

…to be invoked – that is the way that the CLR enumerates the objects that must be assigned to the `item` variable during each iteration of the `foreach` loop.

In your case, the `GetEnumerator()` invocation would cause `theIterator` to be executed again for the same `root`, thereby entering an infinite recursion.

To fix your problem, you need to replace:

```
foreach (var item in (Expression)root)
```

…with:

```
foreach (var item in ((Expression)root).expr)
```

…where `expr` is the name of the `List<object>` property.

Comment: Still causes the stackoverflow exception.

Comment: Combine this fix with [Dan Tao’s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10874492/1149773). You had two causes for your `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you change `GetEnumerator()` to return `this.GetEnumerator()`?

It seems to me that's where your stack overflow is coming from.

Try making it return `theIterator(this).GetEnumerator()`?

Comment: In the original, expr was the `List<object>` that held the data. Since the new iterator would be working on an `Expression` I passed it an expression.

Comment: +1: Another cause of the `StackOverflowException` (although I don’t think it’s the only one).

Comment: You were right the first time, it should be `theIterator(this).GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @soandos: Ha, OK. To be honest I was a little confused by your implementation; anyway I'm glad you got it figured out!